# Why web services cannot participate in Java EE transactions?

Tags: web-services, transactions, jta

I'm trying to understand why a web service cannot be a part of a Java EE transaction like a db operation.

I.e from inside an EJB if I make a DB update and a web service call, there is no way to bind these two steps together in an atomic way.

I read this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-transjta/ and the simplified understanding I get from this article is: Web services are third party offerings and not necessarily Java EE. i.e a web service needs not be served by a Java EE server so a Java EE transaction does not apply to them.

So does this mean if the web service is served by a Java EE server, we can use transactions?